Latest version of QGIS on Windows 7
What is the latest version of QGIS that will run under Windows 7?
I have been running QGIS 3.28 without any problems but I noticed that there is a note on the download page that indicates Windows 7 no longer works since QGIS is now using Python 3.9. However, I wasn't sure if that note applied just to the network installer.

The last QGIS versions provided by OSGeo4W (either the Network installer or the all-in-one stand-alone installer) running on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit are QGIS LTR 3.34.5-1 and QGIS 3.36.1-1.
QGIS LTR versions > 3.34.5-1 and QGIS versions > 3.36.1-1 provided by OSGeo4W don't run on Windows 7.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56604

I reformulate my previous reply with the detailed clarifications provided by Andrea Giudiceandrea.
In September 2022 the incompatibility between Windows 7 with 64-bit code and the new Python 3.9 libraries of QGIS had been resolved.
Unfortunately, as a result of subsequent incompatibilities that arose, QGIS LTR versions greater than 3.34.5-1 and QGIS versions greater than 3.36.1-1 provided by OSGeo4W, including the latest 3.34.11 and 3.38.3, do not work on Windows 7 - 64 bit.
Therefore the latest versions of QGIS that can be installed on Windows 7-based PCs with 64-bit code are the standalone 3.34.5-1 and OSGeo4W 3.36.1-1.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56604
https://pigrecoinfinito-com.translate.goog/2022/09/04/qgis-ritorna-a-funzionare-in-windows-7/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=it&_x_tr_pto=wapp
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48367

This not correct. QGIS LTR versions > 3.34.5-1 and QGIS versions > 3.36.1-1 provided by OSGeo4W, including the latest 3.34.11 and 3.38.3, don't run on Windows 7. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56604

Thanks Andrea for the clarification, I thought that the work done by Jürgen in 2022 had definitively resolved the incompatibilities with Windows 7 64-bit and QGIS .
